# Finding parameter for which integral equals $1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a way to find $b_a\in\mathbb R$ for which
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{ax+b_a}\mathrm{d}x
$$
equals $1$, where the parameter $a$ is given?

---

I am not sure if a closed formula for $b_a$ even exists.

For context, I am experimenting with some data depending on a parameter $c$. I found out that the data points lie on the curve of a function $f_c(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{a_cx+b_c}$. The context suggests that the integral of $f_c$ from $0$ to $1$ equals $1$ (it should be a density function). I already found a closed formula for $a_c$, and wish to obtain $b_c$ now.

Comment: The same methods in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547135/closed-form-expression-for-fx-y-int-01-frac-sqrtt1-ttx2-ty) should work verbatim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a CAS
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{ax+b}\,dx=\frac{\pi  \left(a-2 b \left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b}}-1\right)\right)}{2 a^2}$$ So, if this must equal $1$, then
$$b_a=\frac{(\pi -2 a)^2}{8 \pi } \qquad \text{if} \qquad -1 \leq a \leq 1$$

Notice that the antiderivative exists (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5Bx%281-x%29%5D%2F%28a+x%2Bb%29%2Cx%5D)).

**Edit**

It should be better to write
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{ax+b}\,dx=\frac 1 a\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+c}\,dx \qquad \text{where} \qquad c=\frac b a$$

If $c > 0 $ the result is
$$\frac \pi a   \left(c-\sqrt{c (c+1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right) $$

If $c<0$, the result is
$$\frac \pi a  \left(c+\sqrt{c (c+1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \qquad \text{if} \qquad c<-1$$

Comment: @CiaPan. Using WA, just type *Integrate[Sqrt[x(1-x)]/(a x+b),x]*